# The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request

Tags: php, codeigniter

I installed one product. I got error like this. I dont know how to resolve this. I checked Php.ini file, .htacess file and file permission too. All are correct. Anybody tell the solution.

Error Message :

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webadmin@xxxxxx.xx and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: can you post your code? your .htaccess code and config.php

Comment: so, what did the webserver error log say?

Comment: The server's error log will have details about the 500 error. What you see in the browser is deliberately vague to prevent any internal config/private data from leaking out.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the 404 error showed was because it was trying to write the error to a log, which you do not have enabled:

First thing to do is if you can get in the admin section of your site, make sure you have error reporting set to on:

Here is how to enable error reporting:

system_configuration_ADVANCED_Developer (system>configuration>ADVANCED>Developer)

When you open that tab you'll see a section called "log settings" choose the following:

-enabled to yes 
- System Log File Name: system.log (or you can replace the system with another word like magensys.log)
-Exceptions Log File Name: exception.log

Now both these log files can be found in /var_log (www.domainhere.com/var/log or if it's a local installation magentofolder/var/local)

Try reloading the page where this error occurs and if it does occur again, then open your error log to see the error.

Most of the time it's due to extensions not agreeing with what you are trying to accomplish.

Option 2) Go to app_etc_local (app/etc/local) and delete the local.xml then reload your site and reinstall magento, this will not delete your site just reload your basic settings so you can everything back to normal.

If you could be a little more clear to what kind of product you were installing, where you were installing, etc... that would help pinpoint the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your php error log, if you don't know where it is you can do the following from your terminal:

```
$ -> `php -i | fgrep -i error`
```

You should see an entry for `error_log`. Tail that file and refresh the page, it should display the error.

Comment: Hi, did you get it figured out?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php)
will help you. Try to use

```
<?php
    # test.php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors','On');

    ini_set('error_log','my_file.log');
    foreach(1 as $i);

    ini_set('error_log','');
    foreach(1 as $i);

    ini_set('error_log','/dev/null'); #linux
    foreach(1 as $i);
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing this error because of wrong entries in  httaccs  file. Plz check your http access file